# How to call main function from another header files cpp file

Tags: c++, header-files, program-entry-point

I want to call `main` function form another header files cpp file. where `main` included a header file.
let's call main.cpp has a header file. can I call main.cpp's `main` from header files cpp?

This is main.cpp

```
    #include "another.h"
    int main()
    {
        cout<<"Main";
    }
```

this is another.h

```
   class another
    {
       public:
               void another_func(void);
    };
```

this is another_func.cpp separate file

```
    void another::another_func(void)
    {
       //how do i call main()
    }
```

Comment: The C++ standard prohibits calling `main`: C++ 2017 (draft N4659) 6.6.1 [basic.start.main] 3 says “The function `main` shall not be used within a program…”

Comment: sorry i am new to c++ so please explain in plain english

Comment: The only thing in your `main()` will be a function call to some other function. Simply call it also from another file. For more information see your C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `main` in your own code is not allowed by the C++ standard. If you do, you are in Undefined Behaviour land and your entire program is meaningless.

Only the implementation may call `main` as an entry point to your program.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is special in that it cannot be called (including from inside itself), its address cannot be taken etc.

So you're better off with something like

```
#include "another.h"
int main()
{
    return Main();
}
int Main() {
    std::cout<<"Main\n";
    return 0;
}
```

this is another.h

```
class another
{
   public:
           void another_func(void);
};
```

this is another_func.cpp separate file

```
void another::another_func(void)
{
    Main();
}
```

Comment: when i call ```Main()``` from ```another::another_func(void)``` Error Showing like this ```Main()``` is not declare in this scope

Comment: Looks like compiler is unware of it. So declare it.